# How can I add color to a .txt file in VS Code with python?

Tags: python, colors, txt

I've done a lot of searching for this, and nothing I have found has either seemed simple enough to implement or work for what I'm trying to do.

So, I'm working on a logging system for a Discord bot I'm writing. I have it all down and working, except I'm trying to add colored text to the .txt file I'm using to make it a bit easier for me to distinct between the 3 parts of each line I have down.

The "first part" I suppose is the date and time. I want this to be colored a distinct color, my main choice currently being a vibrant blue, but I'm also thinking of using red.

The "second part" is simply "INFO - " or "ERROR - " depending on if the command fails to run or not.

The "third part" is simply the data of the command - What command was ran, who ran it, where it was ran, and what was put into the command (if applicable).

My bot code is not relevant here as the logging function itself is just raw python, with some datetime in it as well. I am simply attempting to color text in a .txt file via python code, however am willing to use different file types (like .log) and maybe even a VS code extension in order to get the same effect. I'm not sure where else to ask, so I'm asking it here.

It would be appreciated if any provided solutions could be made as simple as possible, as I am legitimately quite dumb and would like to easily understand what is going on, if possible.

If there is no possible answer with what I have here, it would be appreciated if other alternate ways of coloring a log file via python code (as I have described I cannot figure out and would like help with) could be provided.

One final note, I have already looked at the option of using HTML, and have multiple problems with it.
For one, as I am dumb (mentioned previously), I have a slightly harder time comprehending HTML. I'm not sure why, it just doesn't really work in my head. Additionally, I would prefer not having to use HTML as that would require viewing it in a website when I would personally prefer viewing the log via my VS code client.

Here is my relevant code.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

def logCommand(command, author, server, input=None):
    log = open("log.txt", "a")
    time = datetime.now()
    currentTime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    today = date.today()
    part1 = (f"{today} {currentTime} ") #Would like to be green or blue
    if input != None:
        if input == "fail":
            part2 = "ERROR - " #Would like to be red
        else:
            part2 = "INFO - " #Would like to be blue or green
    part3 = f"Command {command} ran by {author} in {server}"
    if input != None and input != "fail":
        part3 += f" with input {input}"
    text = part1 + part2 + part3
    log.write(text)
    log.close()
```

I appreciate any and everything provided with the intent to assist me. Even a simple statement that what I am trying is not possible is greatly appreciated and welcomed, as it will educate me and inform me to look elsewhere for what I am attempting. Thank you all for the assistance!

Comment: Plaintext files (i.e., `*.txt` files) don't support colored text as far as I'm aware. You might want to look into so-called Rich Text `*.rtf` files, though I'm not sure how to apply formatting as part of the text markup - it's typically done *after the fact* in the text editor. The [rtfcre module](https://github.com/sammdot/rtfcre) might help here!

Comment: How will you "read" this file?  In an editor, cat to the command line? Is an html file an acceptable alternative?

Comment: @JonSG I'm using VS Code, so most likely inside the text editor itself. I don't see myself using anything else to view it at the moment.